# Big Gap Between Slideshow and Promotion Area - HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

Like the title said, there is a big gap between the slideshow and the promotional area.

Just to demonstrate my problem, here is a code snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var slideIndex = 0;
    var slideInterval = setInterval(function() {
        next();
    }, 3000);
    
    $("#prev").click(function() {
        prev();
        clearInterval(slideInterval);
    });
    $("#next").click(function() {
        next();
        clearInterval(slideInterval);
    });
    function prev() {
        if(slideIndex < 0) {
            slideIndex = $(".slides").length - 1 - 1;
        }
        else {
            slideIndex--;
        }
        
        showSlides();
    }
    function next() {
        if(slideIndex > $(".slides").length - 1 - 1) {
            slideIndex = 0;
        }
        else {
            slideIndex++;
        }
        
        showSlides();
    }
    function showSlides() {
        $(".slides").not($(".slides")[slideIndex]).each(function() {
            $(this).removeClass("showing");
        });
        $(".slides").eq(slideIndex).addClass("showing");
    }
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap');

body {
    font-family: "Roboto";
    background-color: #525252;
    margin: 0;
    color: white;
}

#logoContainer {
    background-image: url("https://www.whitegrass.ca/images/grass.png");
    width: 100%;
    height: 155px;
    margin: 0;
}

#logo {
    width: 305.25px;
    height: 107.25px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-top: 25px;
}

.lFix {
    clear: left;
    display: block;
}

#mainMenu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #454545;
}

#mainMenu a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#mainMenu li {
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 18px;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #454545;
    transition: background-color 0.5s, border 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s, border 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s, border 0.5s;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.5s, border 0.5s;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #454545;
}

#mainMenu li:hover {
    background-color: #656565;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #08f;
}

#mainMenu #current {
    background-color: #656565;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #08f;
}

#mobileMainMenu {
    /* height: 400px; */
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

#mobileMainMenu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #454545;
}

#mobileMainMenu a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#menuButton {
    color: white;
    display: none;
    padding: 18px;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #454545;
    transition: background-color 0.2s;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.2s;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.2s;
}

#menuButton:hover {
    background-color: #656565;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#mobileMainMenu li {
    color: white;
    display: block;
    padding: 18px;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #454545;
    transition: background-color 0.5s, border 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s, border 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s, border 0.5s;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.5s, border 0.5s;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-left: 2px solid #454545;
}

#mobileMainMenu li:hover {
    background-color: #656565;
    border-left: 2px solid #08f;
}

#mobileMainMenu #current {
    background-color: #656565;
    border-left: 2px solid #08f;
}

@media (max-width: 804px) {
    #mainMenu li {
        display: none;
    }
    
    #menuButton {
        display: block;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 805px) {
    #mobileMainMenu li {
        display: none !important;
    }
}

#menuCheck {
    display: none;
}

#menuCheck:checked ~ #mobileMainMenu {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 5;
}

.space {
    padding: 2px;
}

button {
    display: block;
    border: none;
    background-color: #0074c2;
    padding: 17px;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: roboto;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 1.5px;
    transition: background-color 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.5s;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: #005d9c;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.buttonLink {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.textarea {
    margin: 25px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.titlearea {
    padding: 18px;
    background-color: #08f;
    display: block !important;
}

.titlearea h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#footer {
    display: block;
    background-color: #454545;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    padding: 25px;
    height: 25px;
}

#footer p {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#footer a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    transition: color 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: color 0.5s;
    -o-transition: color 0.5s;
}

#footer a:hover {
    color: #08f;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#footerSpace::after {
    content: "\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0";
}

#footerSpace2::after {
    content: "\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0";
}

.im {
    font-size: 1em !important;
}

#mobileFooter {
    display: none;
    background-color: #454545;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    padding: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}

#mobileFooter p {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#mobileFooter a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    transition: color 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: color 0.5s;
    -o-transition: color 0.5s;
}

#mobileFooter a:hover {
    color: #08f;
    cursor: pointer;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1210px) {
    #footer {
        display: none;
    }
    #mobileFooter {
        display: block;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1066px) {
    #mobileFooter {
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 652px) {
    #mobileFooter {
        font-size: 0.85em;
    }
}

#slide1 {
    background-image: url("https://whitegrass.ca/images/img/slider/slider-bg-1");
}

#slide2 {
    background-image: url("https://whitegrass.ca/images/img/slider/slider-bg-2");
}

#slide3 {
    background-image: url("https://whitegrass.ca/images/img/slider/slider-bg-3");
}

#slideshow {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 478px;
    width: 100%;
}

.slides {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 478px;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: opacity 1s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s;
}

.showing {
    opacity: 1 !important;
    z-index: 2 !important;
}

.slideText {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.slideText * {
    text-align: center;
}

.slideText h1 {
    font-size: 2.5em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 50%);
    padding: 5px;
}

.slideText p {
    font-size: 1em;
    /* background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 50%); */
    padding: 3px;
}

.slideText button {
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
}

@media (max-width: 1206px) {
    .slideText h1 {
        font-size: 2.25em;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 1087px) {
    .slideText h1 {
        font-size: 2em;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 969px) {
    .slideText h1 {
        font-size: 1.75em;
    }
    .slideText p {
        font-size: 0.9em;
    }
    .slideText button {
        padding: 13px;
        font-size: 0.9em;
    }
}

#prev, #next {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: auto;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    padding: 12px;
    transition: background-color 0.2s;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.2s;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.2s;   
    z-index: 3;
}

#next {
    right: 0;
}

#prev:hover, #next:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 50%);
}

#intro {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 500px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

#intro .introCat {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    width: calc(100% / 3.5);
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.introCat h3 {
    text-align: center;
}

.introCat p {
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 256px;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.introCat img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-top: 40px;
}

.introCat .introImgCont {
    display: block;
    width: 142px;
    height: 142px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #656565;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: background-color 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.5s;
}

.introCat:hover .introImgCont {
    background-color: #0074c2;
}

@media (max-width: 1066px) {
    .introCat {
        width: 90% !important;
        float: none !important;
        padding-bottom: 16px !important;
    }

    #intro {
        padding-bottom: 0 !important;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 512px) {
    .introCat {
        width: 85% !important;
        float: none !important;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Home | White Grass Builder &amp; Developer</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.iconmonstr.com/1.3.0/css/iconmonstr-iconic-font.min.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="slideshow.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="logoContainer">
            <a href="index.html"><img id="logo" alt="White Grass" src="https://www.whitegrass.ca/images/logo-text.png" /></a>
            <span class="lFix"></span>
        </div>
        <nav id="mainMenu">
            <ul>
                <a href="index.html"><li id="current">Home</li></a>
                <a href="about.html"><li>About</li></a>
                <a href="services.html"><li>Services</li></a>
                <a href="portfolio.html"><li>Portfolio</li></a>
                <a href="invop.html"><li>Investment Oppertunity</li></a>
                <a href="contact.html"><li>Contact</li></a>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <input type="checkbox" id="menuCheck" />
        <label for="menuCheck"><div id="menuButton">
            <img alt="Menu" src="images/mmm/menu.png" />
        </div></label>
        <nav id="mobileMainMenu">
            <ul>
                <a href="index.html"><li id="current">Home</li></a>
                <a href="about.html"><li>About</li></a>
                <a href="services.html"><li>Services</li></a>
                <a href="portfolio.html"><li>Portfolio</li></a>
                <a href="invop.html"><li>Investment Oppertunity</li></a>
                <a href="contact.html"><li>Contact</li></a>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="space"></div>
        <div id="slideshow">
            <div class="slides showing" id="slide1">
                <div class="slideText">
                    <h1>Welcome to White Grass</h1>
                    <p>Your complete solution to home building</p>
                    <a class="buttonLink" href="portfolio.html"><button>See Our Portfolio</button></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slides" id="slide2">
                <div class="slideText">
                    <h1>Custom Home Builder</h1>
                    <p>Customer satisfaction is our top priority</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slides" id="slide3">
                <div class="slideText">
                    <h1>Professional &amp; Experienced</h1>
                    <p>A history of exceptional homes</p>
                    <a class="buttonLink" href="contact.html"><button>Contact Us Now</button></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <img id="prev" alt="Previous Slide" src="images/slideshow/leftarrow.png" />
            <img id="next" alt="Next Slide" src="images/slideshow/rightarrow.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="intro">
            <div class="introCat">
                <div class="introImgCont">
                    <img alt="House" src="images/intro/house.png" />
                </div>
                <h3>Professional</h3>
                <p>We provide a complete set of construction services to ensure a hassle free home building experience.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="introCat">
                <div class="introImgCont">
                    <img alt="Checkbox" src="images/intro/checkbox.png" />
                </div>
                <h3>Customer Orientated</h3>
                <p>We cater to each customer's unique requirements to build their dream home.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="introCat">
                <div class="introImgCont">
                    <img alt="Thumbs Up" src="images/intro/thumbsup.png" />
                </div>
                <h3>Experienced</h3>
                <p>A proven track record in real estate construction, sales and investment.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <p>Copyright &#169; 2021 – White Grass Builder and Developer Inc. All rights reserved.<span id="footerSpace"></span><a href="mailto:contact@whitegrass.ca"><i class="im im-mail"></i> &nbsp;contact@whitegrass.ca</a><span id="footerSpace2"></span><a href="tel:+1-647-990-7052"><i class="im im-phone"></i> +1-647-990-7052</a></p>
        </div>
        <div id="mobileFooter">
            <p>Copyright &#169; 2021 – White Grass Builder and Developer Inc. All rights reserved.<a href="mailto:contact@whitegrass.ca"></p>
            <p><i class="im im-mail"></i> &nbsp;contact@whitegrass.ca</a><span id="footerSpace2"></span><a href="tel:+1-647-990-7052"><i class="im im-phone"></i> +1-647-990-7052</a></p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And a link to my CodePen to view the problem: https://codepen.io/codezinx/pen/yLVOPrX

My question is how do I get rid of the gap?

**NOTE:** You might notice that some images are missing. That's because I have a lot of my images locally stored on my PC and I somehow failed to embed them. The other images come from the old version of the website I'm currently developing (I'm developing the new one basically and the images are linked to the old website). Next, I am showing the JavaScript so that the slideshow actually functions. Finally, links do not work here (so basically clicking the links will most probably give you an error 404).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reduce `#intro { margin-top: 500px }` to a smaller value. I used `50px` and commented on the line in question within the CSS window of the snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var slideIndex = 0;
    var slideInterval = setInterval(function() {
        next();
    }, 3000);
    
    $("#prev").click(function() {
        prev();
        clearInterval(slideInterval);
    });
    $("#next").click(function() {
        next();
        clearInterval(slideInterval);
    });
    function prev() {
        if(slideIndex < 0) {
            slideIndex = $(".slides").length - 1 - 1;
        }
        else {
            slideIndex--;
        }
        
        showSlides();
    }
    function next() {
        if(slideIndex > $(".slides").length - 1 - 1) {
            slideIndex = 0;
        }
        else {
            slideIndex++;
        }
        
        showSlides();
    }
    function showSlides() {
        $(".slides").not($(".slides")[slideIndex]).each(function() {
            $(this).removeClass("showing");
        });
        $(".slides").eq(slideIndex).addClass("showing");
    }
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap');

body {
    font-family: "Roboto";
    background-color: #525252;
    margin: 0;
    color: white;
}

#logoContainer {
    background-image: url("https://www.whitegrass.ca/images/grass.png");
    width: 100%;
    height: 155px;
    margin: 0;
}

#logo {
    width: 305.25px;
    height: 107.25px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-top: 25px;
}

.lFix {
    clear: left;
    display: block;
}

#mainMenu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #454545;
}

#mainMenu a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#mainMenu li {
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 18px;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #454545;
    transition: background-color 0.5s, border 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s, border 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s, border 0.5s;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.5s, border 0.5s;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #454545;
}

#mainMenu li:hover {
    background-color: #656565;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #08f;
}

#mainMenu #current {
    background-color: #656565;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #08f;
}

#mobileMainMenu {
    /* height: 400px; */
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

#mobileMainMenu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #454545;
}

#mobileMainMenu a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#menuButton {
    color: white;
    display: none;
    padding: 18px;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #454545;
    transition: background-color 0.2s;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.2s;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.2s;
}

#menuButton:hover {
    background-color: #656565;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#mobileMainMenu li {
    color: white;
    display: block;
    padding: 18px;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #454545;
    transition: background-color 0.5s, border 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s, border 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s, border 0.5s;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.5s, border 0.5s;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-left: 2px solid #454545;
}

#mobileMainMenu li:hover {
    background-color: #656565;
    border-left: 2px solid #08f;
}

#mobileMainMenu #current {
    background-color: #656565;
    border-left: 2px solid #08f;
}

@media (max-width: 804px) {
    #mainMenu li {
        display: none;
    }
    
    #menuButton {
        display: block;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 805px) {
    #mobileMainMenu li {
        display: none !important;
    }
}

#menuCheck {
    display: none;
}

#menuCheck:checked ~ #mobileMainMenu {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 5;
}

.space {
    padding: 2px;
}

button {
    display: block;
    border: none;
    background-color: #0074c2;
    padding: 17px;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: roboto;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 1.5px;
    transition: background-color 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.5s;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: #005d9c;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.buttonLink {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.textarea {
    margin: 25px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.titlearea {
    padding: 18px;
    background-color: #08f;
    display: block !important;
}

.titlearea h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#footer {
    display: block;
    background-color: #454545;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    padding: 25px;
    height: 25px;
}

#footer p {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#footer a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    transition: color 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: color 0.5s;
    -o-transition: color 0.5s;
}

#footer a:hover {
    color: #08f;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#footerSpace::after {
    content: "\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0";
}

#footerSpace2::after {
    content: "\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0";
}

.im {
    font-size: 1em !important;
}

#mobileFooter {
    display: none;
    background-color: #454545;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    padding: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}

#mobileFooter p {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#mobileFooter a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    transition: color 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: color 0.5s;
    -o-transition: color 0.5s;
}

#mobileFooter a:hover {
    color: #08f;
    cursor: pointer;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1210px) {
    #footer {
        display: none;
    }
    #mobileFooter {
        display: block;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1066px) {
    #mobileFooter {
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 652px) {
    #mobileFooter {
        font-size: 0.85em;
    }
}

#slide1 {
    background-image: url("https://whitegrass.ca/images/img/slider/slider-bg-1");
}

#slide2 {
    background-image: url("https://whitegrass.ca/images/img/slider/slider-bg-2");
}

#slide3 {
    background-image: url("https://whitegrass.ca/images/img/slider/slider-bg-3");
}

#slideshow {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 478px;
    width: 100%;
}

.slides {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 478px;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: opacity 1s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s;
}

.showing {
    opacity: 1 !important;
    z-index: 2 !important;
}

.slideText {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.slideText * {
    text-align: center;
}

.slideText h1 {
    font-size: 2.5em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 50%);
    padding: 5px;
}

.slideText p {
    font-size: 1em;
    /* background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 50%); */
    padding: 3px;
}

.slideText button {
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
}

@media (max-width: 1206px) {
    .slideText h1 {
        font-size: 2.25em;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 1087px) {
    .slideText h1 {
        font-size: 2em;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 969px) {
    .slideText h1 {
        font-size: 1.75em;
    }
    .slideText p {
        font-size: 0.9em;
    }
    .slideText button {
        padding: 13px;
        font-size: 0.9em;
    }
}

#prev, #next {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: auto;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    padding: 12px;
    transition: background-color 0.2s;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.2s;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.2s;   
    z-index: 3;
}

#next {
    right: 0;
}

#prev:hover, #next:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 50%);
}

#intro {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 50px; /* reduce from 500px */
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

#intro .introCat {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    width: calc(100% / 3.5);
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.introCat h3 {
    text-align: center;
}

.introCat p {
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 256px;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.introCat img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-top: 40px;
}

.introCat .introImgCont {
    display: block;
    width: 142px;
    height: 142px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #656565;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: background-color 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.5s;
}

.introCat:hover .introImgCont {
    background-color: #0074c2;
}

@media (max-width: 1066px) {
    .introCat {
        width: 90% !important;
        float: none !important;
        padding-bottom: 16px !important;
    }

    #intro {
        padding-bottom: 0 !important;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 512px) {
    .introCat {
        width: 85% !important;
        float: none !important;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Home | White Grass Builder &amp; Developer</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.iconmonstr.com/1.3.0/css/iconmonstr-iconic-font.min.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="slideshow.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="logoContainer">
            <a href="index.html"><img id="logo" alt="White Grass" src="https://www.whitegrass.ca/images/logo-text.png" /></a>
            <span class="lFix"></span>
        </div>
        <nav id="mainMenu">
            <ul>
                <a href="index.html"><li id="current">Home</li></a>
                <a href="about.html"><li>About</li></a>
                <a href="services.html"><li>Services</li></a>
                <a href="portfolio.html"><li>Portfolio</li></a>
                <a href="invop.html"><li>Investment Oppertunity</li></a>
                <a href="contact.html"><li>Contact</li></a>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <input type="checkbox" id="menuCheck" />
        <label for="menuCheck"><div id="menuButton">
            <img alt="Menu" src="images/mmm/menu.png" />
        </div></label>
        <nav id="mobileMainMenu">
            <ul>
                <a href="index.html"><li id="current">Home</li></a>
                <a href="about.html"><li>About</li></a>
                <a href="services.html"><li>Services</li></a>
                <a href="portfolio.html"><li>Portfolio</li></a>
                <a href="invop.html"><li>Investment Oppertunity</li></a>
                <a href="contact.html"><li>Contact</li></a>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="space"></div>
        <div id="slideshow">
            <div class="slides showing" id="slide1">
                <div class="slideText">
                    <h1>Welcome to White Grass</h1>
                    <p>Your complete solution to home building</p>
                    <a class="buttonLink" href="portfolio.html"><button>See Our Portfolio</button></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slides" id="slide2">
                <div class="slideText">
                    <h1>Custom Home Builder</h1>
                    <p>Customer satisfaction is our top priority</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slides" id="slide3">
                <div class="slideText">
                    <h1>Professional &amp; Experienced</h1>
                    <p>A history of exceptional homes</p>
                    <a class="buttonLink" href="contact.html"><button>Contact Us Now</button></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <img id="prev" alt="Previous Slide" src="images/slideshow/leftarrow.png" />
            <img id="next" alt="Next Slide" src="images/slideshow/rightarrow.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="intro">
            <div class="introCat">
                <div class="introImgCont">
                    <img alt="House" src="images/intro/house.png" />
                </div>
                <h3>Professional</h3>
                <p>We provide a complete set of construction services to ensure a hassle free home building experience.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="introCat">
                <div class="introImgCont">
                    <img alt="Checkbox" src="images/intro/checkbox.png" />
                </div>
                <h3>Customer Orientated</h3>
                <p>We cater to each customer's unique requirements to build their dream home.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="introCat">
                <div class="introImgCont">
                    <img alt="Thumbs Up" src="images/intro/thumbsup.png" />
                </div>
                <h3>Experienced</h3>
                <p>A proven track record in real estate construction, sales and investment.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <p>Copyright &#169; 2021 – White Grass Builder and Developer Inc. All rights reserved.<span id="footerSpace"></span><a href="mailto:contact@whitegrass.ca"><i class="im im-mail"></i> &nbsp;contact@whitegrass.ca</a><span id="footerSpace2"></span><a href="tel:+1-647-990-7052"><i class="im im-phone"></i> +1-647-990-7052</a></p>
        </div>
        <div id="mobileFooter">
            <p>Copyright &#169; 2021 – White Grass Builder and Developer Inc. All rights reserved.<a href="mailto:contact@whitegrass.ca"></p>
            <p><i class="im im-mail"></i> &nbsp;contact@whitegrass.ca</a><span id="footerSpace2"></span><a href="tel:+1-647-990-7052"><i class="im im-phone"></i> +1-647-990-7052</a></p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[Browser dev tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) are your friend. And that's how you can often quickly locate problems like this in your code for a quick fix.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have a margin-top: 500px; in your CSS for your Intro ID, this makes a 500px gap above where the Intro ID items are.

This is how the CSS looks now without the gap:

```
#intro {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```